# Implementing expected<E, T> according to proposal n4015

Tags: c++, c++11

I started implementing `expected<E, T>` according to the proposal and I ran into a problem.
When describing the monadic functionality (5.9) it is stated in bind that if the result is already wrapped in context (`expected<E, T>`) it shouldn't be wrapped again.

How I implemented it is that bind had 2 overloads (with `enable_if`), one for functors that return an instantiation of `expected` which the implementation didn't wrap it in context and one for those that returned other types which it did. I ran into a problem where the non-wrapping version, in the absence of a value in the caller had to return a default constructed `expected<E1, T1>` which gave the expected a default constructed error value.

That caused further continuations of the returned expected to lose the context of the error that caused the default construction.

Perhaps I should treat the context which was referred to as `is_same<expected<E,T>, functor_ret_type>` and here in case of an error in the caller I can forward "this" and keep the context of the error, but that would cause functors returning `expected<E1, E2>` to return `expected<E, expected<E1, E2>>`

Assuming the following about the class:

```
E& error(); //returns the stored error
T& operator*(); //returns a reference to the stored value
bool has_value(); //returns true if the expected value is present, false if the error is present
```

Here is how I had it implemented at first:

```
//overload for wrapping functors
template<typename Functor>
auto bind(Functor functor) -> std::enable_if<is_instance<expected, 
                                             decltype(functor(**this))>::value,
                                             decltype(functor(**this))>::type
{
    using result_type = decltype(functor(**this));
    if (this->has_value())
    {
        return functor(**this);
    }
    return result_type();
}


//overload for non wrapping functors
template<typename Functor>
auto bind(Functor functor) -> std::enable_if<!is_instance<expected, 
                                             decltype(functor(**this))>::value,
                                             expected<E, decltype(functor(**this))>>::type
{
    using result_type = decltype(functor(**this));
    if (has_value())
    {
        return { functor(**this) };
    }
    return expected<E, result_type>(this->error());
}
```

Here you can see that in the first overload, if we have no value, we return a default constructed `expected<E, T>` of the type that `functor` returns, which holds a default constructed error type `E`, which makes us lose the context of the original error due to which functor wasn't called.

If I am to interpret the described behavior as "if functor returns `expected<E, T>` of the same type as the one which the bind was called for don't wrap otherwise wrap" we can have the following implementation:

```
//overload for wrapping functors
template<typename Functor>
auto bind(Functor functor) -> std::enable_if<is_same<expected<E, T>, 
                                             decltype(functor(**this))>::value,
                                             decltype(functor(**this))>::type
{
    if (this->has_value())
    {
        return functor(**this);
    }
    return *this;
}


//overload for non wrapping functors
template<typename Functor>
auto bind(Functor functor) -> std::enable_if<!is_same<expected<E, T>,
                                             decltype(functor(**this))>::value,
                                             expected<E, decltype(functor(**this))>>::type
{
    using result_type = decltype(functor(**this));
    if (has_value())
    {
        return { functor(**this) };
    }
    return expected<E, result_type>(this->error());
}
```

Here, if no value is present in the wrapping overload, we forward `this` which allows us to know what was the initial error, but if functor returns `expected<E1, T1>` the result would be a wrapped `expected<E, expected<E1, T1>>`

A third approach I can think of is only treat `E` as the context, which would be a little less restrictive, and would allow to unwrap a functor which returns `expected<E, T1>`, but the problem for `expected<E1, T1>` is still present.

Which is the correct approach? Maybe there is another approach that I missed altogether?

Thank you.

Comment: +1 but vote to close. You must give [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: n4015 doesn't have a section 5.9.

Comment: @ikh added a code example to illustrate my problem, can the question be reopened?

Comment: I still don't understand which section you're referring to. Are you reading a different version of the paper from https://isocpp.org/files/papers/n4015.pdf?

Comment: @ecatmur, I was also wondering. http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4015.pdf does contain a section 5.9, it is dated 6 days after the one on iso.org.

Comment: What is `**this` supposed to do?

Comment: @BЈовић `expected<E, T>` has a pointer-like interface, like `optional<T>`; `(*this).operator*()` accesses the contained value (assuming the expected contains a value and not an error state).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`bind` is defined in terms of `unwrap`:

> ```
> template <class Ex,class F>
> ’see below’ expected<E,T>::bind(F&& func)
> ```
>
> *Returns:*
>   - if `bool(*this)` returns `unwrap(expected<E, decltype(func(move(val)))>(func(move(val))))`, otherwise returns `get_unexpected()`.

In https://isocpp.org/files/papers/n4015.pdf and in http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4015.pdf `unwrap` is only given non-trivial semantics for `expected<E,expected<E,U>>`; that is, the two unexpected types `E` must be the same:

> ```
> template <class E, class U>
> constexpr expected<E,U> expected<E,expected<E,U>>::unwrap() const&;
> ```
>
> *Returns:*
>   - If `bool(*this)` then `**this`. else `get_unexpected()`

If there are two different unexpected types `E1`, `E2` then `unwrap` has no effect.